# Adding new footer to a folder of word documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, footer

I an using a code copied from "Macropod" (sorry if the name is incorrect) to replace every header and footer in a folder of documents with a new header and footer as displayed in the macro document. It is slightly altered to apply to only footers. This works, but my problem is that it leaves an extra paragraph mark on a line by itself at the end of the footer text and I cannot figure out where to add something that would remove the extra paragraph mark. When doing this copy/paste function manually, only a backspace is required to remove the extra paragraph mark. I've tried adding it a few different ways, but it either does nothing or produces an error. The macro text is provided below.

```
Sub UpdateDocumentFooters()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim wdDocTgt As Document, wdDocSrc As Document
Dim Sctn As Section, HdFt As HeaderFooter
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Set wdDocSrc = ActiveDocument
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
    If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> wdDocSrc.FullName Then
        Set wdDocTgt = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
        With wdDocTgt
            For Each Sctn In .Sections
                'For footers
                For Each HdFt In Sctn.Footers
                    With HdFt
                        If .Exists Then
                            If Sctn.Index = 1 Then
                                wdDocSrc.Sections.First.Footers(HdFt.Index).Range.Copy
                                .Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
                                .Range.Characters.Last = vbNullString
                            ElseIf .LinkToPrevious = False Then
                                wdDocSrc.Sections.First.Footers(HdFt.Index).Range.Copy
                                .Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
                                .Range.Characters.Last = vbNullString
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
            Next
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With
    End If
    strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDocSrc = Nothing: Set wdDocTgt = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Have reviewed the responses below, but no improvement yet.

I start with this:
[Footer to Replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxPIA.jpg)
And want to get this:
[Desired Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sascr.jpg)
But end up with this:
[Resulting Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rdOt.jpg)

Comment: That suggests your source document also has and extra paragraph break in the footer. Remove that, or add another instance of: .Range.Characters.Last = vbNullString

Comment: You could try replacing a double paragraph mark in your footer with a single one. For some reason, when text is manually pasted into a footer, you can end up with the double paragraph mark, even if the original (blank) paragraph mark in the footer is selected prior to the paste.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon If you care to read the code, you will see that existing code already deletes the extraneous empty paragraph after pasting...

Comment: I did read the code. As you know, Paul, doing a replace will catch all double paragraph marks. Deleting the last character ought to get rid of that last paragraph mark but it apparently is not working.